# How can I handle the situation opposite to my condition?

Tags: c#

I have a `foreach` loop where the code doesn't need to run in one special case. I've done it like this:

```
if (!IsZoom && entry.StartDate.Year != Year && entry.EndDate.Year != Year)
{
}
else
{
    // my code...
}
```

Somehow I am not happy with that. Is it maybe better to write this as follows?

```
bool foo = !IsZoom && entry.StartDate.Year != Year && entry.EndDate.Year != Year;
if (!foo)
{
    // my code...
}
```

Comment: What do you think !!!

Comment: _What's the better code?_ How do you define _better code_? Even if there is a difference between these, probably you will **never** notice that. And of course, this question doesn't fit here. Stackoverflow is for specific programming problems.

Comment: I think belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you are asking this with respect to readability then no. 2 is the better code.

Answer (score 5):

Reverse your logic. Invert all your boolean expressions, and replace `AND` with `OR`:

```
if (IsZoom || entry.StartDate.Year == Year || entry.EndDate.Year == Year) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, glad you managed to get it in before the question was closed.